# Проблемное отображение блоков в цикле while

Tags: php

```
                                       <?php
                        session_start(); 
                        include "configuration/db.php";
                        
                       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($zakaz)){
                        $id=$row['id'];
                        $name=$row['name_project'];
                            echo '<div class="tape-wrap__col">
                                <div class="tape__card tape__card_first">
                                    <span class="tape__card-title">Отклики на заказ:</span>
                                    <p class="tape__card-sub-title">'; echo $name; echo'</p>
                                </div>';
                                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($otklikk)){
                                $id_zakaza = $rows['n_zakaza'];
                                $comment = $rows['comment'];
                                $time = $rows['time_otklika'];
                                echo '<div class="tape__card">
                                    <div class="tape__card_items">
                                        <span class="tape__card-data">'; echo $time; echo '</span>
                                        

                                        <p class="tape__card-title"><span class="tape__card-title_color">Отклик от </span>архитектора
                                            № 11 </p>
                                        <p class="tape__card-info">'; echo $comment; echo '</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                            ?>
```

Существует следующий код, который выводит название заказа и комментарии в двух циклах. Заказ с `$name` выводит в разные блоки, а комментарии к ним выводятся под первый блок только. Как можно скрепить вывод, чтобы каждый блок комментариев был под своим блоком заказа? Что упустил? Есть `$id` заказа и `$id_zakaza` в таблице комментариев.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: конкатенацию строк принципиально не используете? Так же принципиально не форматируете код в вопросе по левому краю? Какие комментарии у вас в `$otklikk` лежат, такие и выводит

Comment: @ArchDemon

Выводит в один блок, а привязаны на скриншоте которые показаны ко второму... Вот и спросил, как это можно решить, что забыл учесть...

Comment: Выведите в каждом заказе `$id`, а в каждом отклике `$id_zakaza`. Прикрепите новое изображение

Comment: @ArchDemon
Прикрепил

Comment: теперь прикрепите запрос, который выбирает `$otklikk`. Там же явно указаны все отклики независимо от id заказа. А для следующего заказа у вас выборка откликов не делается. Вы либо запрос откликов делаете для каждого заказа, либо складывайте в массив все отклики, а потом выбирайте только те, которые соответствуют конкретному заказу

Comment: @ArchDemon
$otkliki = "SELECT * FROM otkliki WHERE zakazchik = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
$otklikk = mysqli_query($link, $otkliki);

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй этот вариант:

```
<?php

    session_start(); 
    include "configuration/db.php";
    $html = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($zakaz)){
        $id=$row['id'];
        $name=$row['name_project'];
        $html .='<div class="tape-wrap__col">
            <div class="tape__card tape__card_first">
                <span class="tape__card-title">Отклики на заказ:</span>
                <p class="tape__card-sub-title">'; 
        $html .= $name.'</p></div>';
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($otklikk)){
            $id_zakaza = $rows['n_zakaza'];
            $comment = $rows['comment'];
            $time = $rows['time_otklika'];
            $html .= '<div class="tape__card">
                <div class="tape__card_items">
                    <span class="tape__card-data">'; 
            $html .= $time.'</span><p class="tape__card-title"><span class="tape__card-title_color">Отклик от </span>архитектора № 11 </p> <p class="tape__card-info">'; 
            $html .= $comment.'</p></div></div>';
        }
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
    
    echo $html;

?>
```